# Adding custom text above and below a buffer

Tags: evil, text-editing

Is there an easy way to wrap a buffer in emacs with text of my choice? For e.g if my selected buffer is like this,

```
This is the first line of a verse with ।
And here comes the second line ॥ 1.2 ॥
```

I want to add custom markers to the top and bottom of the verse like this:

```
\begin{myverse}
This is the first line of a verse with ।
And here comes the second line ॥ 1.2 ॥ 
\end{myverse}
```

I'm running evil mode in emacs 27.1 on OSX. Right now I copy each of the tags `\begin{myverse}` and `\end{myverse}` into named vim buffers, move the cursor to the right location and paste the desired text. I'm hoping there's a faster way of accomplishing this and am open to any solutions in emacs or vim.

EDIT 1: I believe there's an emacs way to move to the beginning of a buffer, add a newline insert some text, again move to the end of that buffer, add a newline and insert text.

Comment: By framing the question in terms of wrapping a buffer with text at the beginning and end thereof, the answers will be different than what would otherwise be indicated by the minimal working example (which wraps a selection with LaTeX code, and does not necessitate being the sole text within the buffer in order to wrap said text).

Comment: @lawlist this is my MWE. The block around which I want to add wrappers is in unicode and hence I chose to provide english text instead.

Comment: I suspect you want something more complex, but the question is not written in such a manner so as to let the forum participants fully understand the context.  Here is a simple example you can try out by typing `M-x eval-expression RET (let ((beg-text "\\begin{myverse}") (end-text "\\end{myverse}")) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (insert beg-text "\n") (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "\n" end-text))) RET`  NOTE:  There are built-in solutions for surrounding text with LaTeX code, as well as using the popular AUCTex library.  There are also skeleton libraries designed for buffer inserts.